# Accessing SQL Database from a seperate directory

Tags: php, html

I am coding a website which links into the service desk software that I am using. The name of the service desk package is OTRS.  The name of the parent directory for the software is named"OTRS", within this directory there are 3 directories "Apache", "mysql" and "OTRS".  OTRS holds the .pl files associated with the service desk software.  "mysql" holds the databases for the OTRS and any custom database that are created. The "Apache" directory holds custom user-made webpages.

Within the "Apache" directory under "htdocs" I would like to create a page which displays how many open tickets are in the service desk. So far I have written the following:

```
<body
height: 100%; 
width: 490px;>
<?php
//mysql conector
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","otrs","xxxxxxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dashboard", $con);

?>

<div id="hig9tv">
<center><p>


<table id='higtable2' border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news"); 


$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=$num-1;
while ($i != -1) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"text");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"time");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");

?>
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width='80px'><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><div id="tiny"><?php echo "$f3 $f2" ; ?></div></font><hr></td>
</tr>
  <?php
$i--;
}
?>
</table>

</p></center>
</div>

</body>
```

However nothing is displayed in the div when I open the page.  The data is stored in the "mySQL" directory under

> mysql/data

is there anyway to link into the database stored in this directory from the Apache?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to think about where the Database-Server saves your Database! When the Database-Server is running you can choose any Database which is linked to the Database-Server. Also have a view on this topic [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) it gives you an easier way of handling data you've fetched out of your Database.

Comment: `The data is stored in the "mySQL" directory under` are these `.sql` files?

Comment: @AlexP the files in the my sql directory are in a sub-directory's by database name, the database files I am after are in a directory labelled "dashboard".  The files within this directory are .FRM, MYD, MYI. Each table  has on each of these file types.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a strict client-server application. As such it is not possible to access its files, such as `.myd` and `.myi` files directly without going through a MySQL instance the clean way. Probably the OTRS product is running its own MySQL instance internally, which you should be able to connect to from the same host. You'll need to connect to the same host, on the same port, with the same credentials, and select the same DB. Forget the files, they don't matter to anyone but the MySQL instance providing structured and secured access to them.

You should be able to find in the OTRS `.pl` files how it connects to the database, if need be with a few simple *nix commands, such as:

```
grep -ir database OTRS/
```

This should show all files containing the word `database`. 99 out of 100 times this should help you find the credentials and host information easily enough.